# Error "(get) unknown parameter: 'personFields'" when following examples in Google People API documentation

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-people-api

I am trying to use the Google People API to add and update my Google contacts. I have set up the API almost verbatim with the example code given in Google's documentation (https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started). I get an error for the following line of code, which again comes verbatim from the documentation:

```
$profile = $people_service->people->get('people/me', array('personFields' => 'names,emailAddresses'));
```

The error is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(get) unknown parameter: 'personFields'' in /home/danbak15/bakerlegalservicesmo.com/office/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:147 Stack trace: #0 /home/danbak15/bakerlegalservicesmo.com/office/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/People/Resource/People.php(52): Google_Service_Resource->call('get', Array, 'Google_Service_...') #1 /home/danbak15/bakerlegalservicesmo.com/office/BLScontacts.php(36): Google_Service_People_Resource_People->get('people/me', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/danbak15/bakerlegalservicesmo.com/office/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Service/Resource.php on line 147
```

I have seen an answer to a similar question ([Can't access my profile data when accessing google-people API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490141/cant-access-my-profile-data-when-accessing-google-people-api)) suggest using the Google_Service_PeopleService class instead of the Google_Service_People class as called for in the documentation. However, when I try to do this, I get another error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "errors": [ { "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "domain": "global", "reason": "unauthorized" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } ' in /home/danbak15/bakerlegalservicesmo.com/office/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /home/danbak15/bakerlegalservicesmo.com/office/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'G in /home/danbak15/bakerlegalservicesmo.com/office/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

At this point, I am at a total loss. I would like to use Google Contacts to keep track of my contacts and would like to be able to work with Google Contacts via PHP so that I can add them to my database. Can anyone shed any light on this? Thank you in advance for any help!

UPDATE:
I tried moving the page to a local server on my computer (forgetting that Google redirects the page to my website) to see if I could get a different result from a different server. Somehow, magically, it worked when I tried to access the script from my website—for about 15-30 minutes or so. Then, I got the same error as before. If I run the page from my localhost server, I will get caught in an endless authorization redirect loop (to be expected given that Google redirects me to the online page), but then the online page will work for a time.

At this point, I can't begin to guess where the issue is. Does this make sense to anyone else?

Comment: Are you positive that you have the latest version of the Client Library?

Comment: I have the same problem, but using the Google_Service_PeopleService fixed it for me; I suggest you focus on resolving the second error.

Comment: I am using version 2.2.0 of the Google API PHP Client library, which I believe to be the correct version (though I could always be mistaken). I am somewhat at a loss about the authentication credentials error when using Google_Service_PeopleService. I have OAuth 2 credentials, which work just fine when using the Google_Service_People class. It's only when I use the Google_Service_PeopleService class that it throws an error. Is there something in my credentials I should look at or change?

Comment: @DanielBaker you correctly set `$people_service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);`? Perhaps you need to reauthenticate yourself as user?

Comment: @Isaiah Thanks for the help! How can I reauthenticate myself as a user? I cleared my browsing data and then reloaded the page, but got the same error. Is this something I can do through the developer console?

Comment: @DanielBaker perhaps revoking your user consent / API access. And granting it again or disabling & re-enabling the API in the dashboard has any effect?

Answer (score 4):

This worked fine for me:

```
$scopes[] = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';
$client->setScopes($scopes);
$service = new Google_Service_People($client);
$optParams =   ['requestMask.includeField' => 'person.names'];
$connections = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams)->getConnections();
foreach ($connections as $connection) {
  if (!empty($connection->getNames()[0])) {
    print $connection->getNames()[0]->getDisplayName() . "\n" . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: tried the above method, but in my case i get $connections empty array. anything i may be missing? cause the same account used to return connections earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I know whats happens.
My English not very well so I hope you can understand what I mean..

In my case, I'm using Google_Service_People class (src\Google\Service\People.php) and get same error as you. So I take a look about People.php and see this :

```
$this->people = new Google_Service_People_Resource_People(
    $this,
    $this->serviceName,
    'people',
    array(
      'methods' => array(
        'get' => array(
          'path' => 'v1/{+resourceName}',
          'httpMethod' => 'GET',
          'parameters' => array(
            'resourceName' => array(
              'location' => 'path',
              'type' => 'string',
              'required' => true,
            ),
            'requestMask.includeField' => array(  // <= This is the problem.
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

I check the official document and it say "[requestMask.includeField is already DEPRECATED.](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/RequestMask)" but it still in api's code by somehow.

So I change it to this :

```
$this->people = new Google_Service_People_Resource_People(
    $this,
    $this->serviceName,
    'people',
    array(
      'methods' => array(
        'get' => array(
          'path' => 'v1/{+resourceName}',
          'httpMethod' => 'GET',
          'parameters' => array(
            'resourceName' => array(
              'location' => 'path',
              'type' => 'string',
              'required' => true,
            ),
            'personFields' => array(  // <- Change to 'personFields'
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            ),
          ),
```

After that every thing go well.

If you are using **Google API Client Libraries from PHP**. This client library is in **beta**. So there something in their api doesn't look like how it exactly is in their api document.

So that is my case. English not my language so I hope you can understand what I trying to describe.

Comment: my code was working till 24th August, suddenly it stopped working and error(exception) i get is for requestMask.includeField. tried to add personFileds to optParams but it gives errorGoogle_Exception: (list) unknown parameter: 'personFields' .  what to do now? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

John Rodriguez solved the issue. Thank you! My library is a little bit different, but the problem was the same. In my case I am using the Google_Service_PeopleService class instead of the Google_Service_People class. The path to the file I changed is: google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/PeopleService.php. In this case, $this->people is a Google_Service_PeopleService_Resource_People class which contains an array of methods. I commented out the depreciated code. Here is the relevant code:

```
$this->people = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Resource_People(
    $this,
    $this->serviceName,
    'people',
    array(
      'methods' => array(
        'createContact' => array(
              ...
            ),
          ),
        ),'deleteContact' => array(
            ...
            ),
          ),
        ),'get' => array(
          'path' => 'v1/{+resourceName}',
          'httpMethod' => 'GET',
          'parameters' => array(
            'resourceName' => array(
              'location' => 'path',
              'type' => 'string',
              'required' => true,
            ),
            'personFields' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            ),
 /*         'requestMask.includeField' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            ), */
          ),
        ),'getBatchGet' => array(
          'path' => 'v1/people:batchGet',
          'httpMethod' => 'GET',
          'parameters' => array(
            'personFields' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            ),
/*          'requestMask.includeField' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
            ), */
            'resourceNames' => array(
              'location' => 'query',
              'type' => 'string',
              'repeated' => true,
            ),
          ),
        ),'updateContact' => array(
           ...
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

So far this has worked as it should, but I have not thoroughly tested it yet. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. How about choice me as accepted answer ?  ;-)